# python-marshmallow: deserializing nested schema with only one exposed key

Tags: python, nested, marshmallow

I am trying to serialize a list of nested objects as scalar values by taking only one field from the nested item. Instead of `[{key: value}, ...]` I want to receive `[value1, value2, ...]`.

Code:

```
from marshmallow import *

class MySchema(Schema):
    key = fields.String(required=True)

class ParentSchema(Schema):
    items = fields.Nested(MySchema, only='key', many=True)
```

Given the above schemas, I want to serialize some data:

```
>>> data = {'items': [{'key': 1}, {'key': 2}, {'key': 3}]}
>>> result, errors = ParentSchema().dump(data)
>>> result
{'items': ['1', '2', '3']}
```

This works as expected, giving me the list of scalar values. However, when trying to deserialize the data using the models above, the data is suddenly invalid:

```
>>> data, errors = ParentSchema().load(result)
>>> data
{'items': [{}, {}, {}]}
>>> errors
{'items': {0: {}, '_schema': ['Invalid input type.', 'Invalid input type.', 'Invalid input type.'], 1: {}, 2: {}}}
```

Is there any configuration option I am missing or is this simply not possible?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand Your questions, but can You confirm it sounds you are asking about this test example:
https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/blob/433ba6c03306760b1c5d3bed12436525f401dd11/tests/test_schema.py#L364
 ( test_default_many_symmetry )
Is that correct ?

Comment: The test you have linked serializes each user to `{"name": "name1"}`. What I would like to do is to serialize each user to `"name1"`, especially for the `many=True` use case, which should dump to `["King Arthur", "Sir Lancelot"]` instead of `[{'name': 'King Arthur'}, {'name': 'Sir Lancelot'}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone stumbling across the same issue, this is the workaround I am using currently:

```
class MySchema(Schema):
    key = fields.String(required=True)

    def load(self, data, *args):
        data = [
            {'key': item} if isinstance(item, str) else item
            for item in data
        ]
        return super().load(data, *args)


class ParentSchema(Schema):
    items = fields.Nested(MySchema, only='key', many=True)
```